# Query about the Python fnmatch module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-interpolation, fnmatch

I was searching for the `fnmatch` module, and along the way, I came across a statement where I didn’t get what is happening… can anyone help me? I need to know what purpose the `-25` serves in this code:

`print 'Filename: %-25s %s' % (name, fnmatch.fnmatchcase(name, pattern))`

Answer (score 1):

The `%-25s` stands for a string comprising 25 spaces. It can as well be replaced with `25*" "`.

The above line of code can be written as:

```
a_string_of_spaces = 25*" "
X = fnmatch.fnmatchcase(filename, pattern)
print("Filename:", name, a_string_of_spaces, X)
```

According to the python documentation:

> `fnmatch.fnmatchcase(filename, pattern)`: 
>   Test whether filename matches pattern, returning True or False; the comparison is case-sensitive and does not apply os.path.normcase()

Thus, the function parameter `filename` is checked for patterns of type `pattern`. The function then returns a boolean value of `True` or `False`

So, in entirety, that line of code prints something like this (`FILE_NAME` = name of the file, the pattern of `PATTERN` has matched with the file):

```
Filename: FILE_NAME                           True
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I know about that but  my  concern was with  %-25s only I got most of the  code but  thanks for the explanation

Comment: Oh good! In such a case please specify which part of the code is not clear. Anyway, a longer explanation is  better for the ppl who have similar doubts... Accept the answer if you find it helpful   : )

Comment: Yaa by seeing the confusion i  edited my question :)

Comment: Edited my answer too